# fade out in angularjs without using ng-animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want once the checkbox is check, instead of disappaear instantly it fade out.

I used setimeout but not nice, and I try to avoid jquery to stay clean. Is it possible to achieve without using ng-animate?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sqo1JGCgda9ywR1OR6Me?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3

** change your css code to this:**

```
.done-true {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: fadeOut 2s;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut
{
from {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
to {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;

}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fadeOut
{
from {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
to {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
}
```